# Proof that (prev n) <= m starting from n <= m

Tags: agda

I have the next definition:

```
data Nat : Set where
  zero : Nat
  succ : Nat -> Nat

prev : Nat -> Nat
prev zero = zero
prev (succ n) = n

data _<=_ : Nat -> Nat -> Set where
  z<=n : forall {n} -> zero <= n
  s<=s : forall {n m} -> (n<=m : n <= m) -> (succ n) <= (succ m)
```

It easy to proof the next lemma:

```
lem-prev : {x y : Nat} -> x <= y -> (prev x) <= (prev y)
lem-prev z<=n = z<=n
lem-prev (s<=s t) = t
```

But I can't find a way to proof the next lemma:

```
lem-prev' : {x y : Nat} -> x <= y -> (prev x) <= y
```

I can change definition of `<=` to the next:

```
data _<='_ : Nat -> Nat -> Set where
  z<=n' : forall {n} -> zero <=' n
  s<=s' : forall {n m} -> (n<=m : n <=' m) -> (succ n) <=' m
```

In that case I can proof `lem-prev'`:

```
lem-prev' : {x y : Nat} -> x <=' y -> (prev x) <=' y
lem-prev' z<=n' = z<=n'
lem-prev' (s<=s' t) = t
```

But now I can't proof `lem-prev`.

Is there a way to proof both lemmas for `<=` and/or `<='`?
If no, then how should I change the definition to make it possible?

ADD: The solution using hammar's helper lemma:

```
lem-prev : {x y : Nat} -> x <= y -> (prev x) <= y
lem-prev z<=n = z<=n
lem-prev (s<=s prev-n<=prev-m) = weaken (prev-n<=prev-m)
```

Comment: I don't agree with your suggested redefinition of `<=`, instead I think you have to start from `zero <= (succ n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this lemma:

```
weaken : {x y : Nat} -> x <= y -> x <= succ y
weaken z<=n = z<=n
weaken (s<=s n<=m) = s<=s (weaken n<=m)
```

Comment: argh! It took 3 hours for me to get the idea :) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

you can find a proof of that lemma in the standard library
http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/listings/lib/Data.Nat.Properties.html#10457

Comment: Thank you! How did you find it? I there anything like hoogle but for agda?

Comment: unfortunately not, i tend to just do a textual search on the sources or browse likely modules